# RadioButton control Text wrapping under the control

Tags: asp.net, css

Please see the below image.The aspx code is placed below the image

[image]

```
<div>
    <asp:RadioButton  runat="server" ID="radiobtn" 
         Text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and 
         typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard 
         dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley 
         of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived 
          not only five centuries," />
    <br />
    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="RadioButton1" 
          Text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and 
          typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard 
          dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley 
          of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived 
          not only five centuries, " />
     <br />
     <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="RadioButton2" 
          Text=" Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and 
          typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard 
          dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley 
          of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived 
          not only five centuries," />
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly you want???

Comment: I want to display all the contents starting in the same position. The second line content "to make a type" need to display exactly below the first line content .

Comment: Elaborate on what you want. Based on that picture I don't know what you are attempting to do here

Comment: The second line of contents need to move right , want to display after the radio button and below the "Lorem Ipsum" content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the div padding-left and then negatively margin the radio button. You'll need to float it left too to make it line up correctly:

```
div {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

input {
  margin: 3px 0 0 -20px;
  float: left;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/awuQUBeGu/3/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

as per you said... please see this fiddle..

http://jsbin.com/efAZIjok/1/edit?html,output

Comment: It's not tabular data

Comment: but atleast he can use that... as he hasnt used any css.. thats why i have suggested him this simple answer..